# How can firebase 3 query or angularfire2 filter pipe used to display snapshot data in tabular format with sum/total

Tags: firebase, angularfire2

My firebase schema is as below:

```
{
  "orders" : {

    “-Shjy4X7atpPy12345Qum" : {
      "qty" : 1,
      "amount" : 10000,
      "payment_type” : "Cash”,
      "productId" : “-ShWSex7Hjit_mYrwuBA”,
      "productPrice" : 13000,
      "u_id" : “aABCW88eNIge4ysb9TDeTHESK4"
    },

“-Ahjy6X9atpBy3435Hki” : {
      "qty" : 1,
      "amount" : 20000,
      "payment_type” : "Card”,
      "productId" : “-AhWFet9Hjit_mGrwuPA”,
      "productPrice" : 13000,
      "u_id" : “aABCW88eNIge4ysb9TDeTHESK4"
    }
}

}
```

Desired output:

Orders

```
Product--------------------Quantity---------------Price
-ShWSex7Hjit_mYrwuBA-------   1    ---------------10000
-AhWFet9Hjit_mGrwuPA-------   1    ---------------10000
```

Grand Total : 20000

Can this be achieved in Firebase query:

```
{ query: {orderByChild: 'productId', equalTo: 'productId'}
```

or by using angular pipes ?

Solution is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest one improvement in your DB schema to make it easier. Since a order can contain multiple products, maybe you can create a node under orders called "cart" which will have Key-Value pairs of productId (as key) and quantity (as value).

```
{ 
  orders:
      cart:
          productId_1 : quantity_1,
          productId_2 : quantity_2,
}
```

Now you can just read the "cart" node & each object of that node will have $key as productId - use that to retrieve price of the product. and $value is the quantity. Now you have all values you need.